# Set app.values from reading a file

Tags: angularjs

Read from a json file and add content as app.values. I need to do this only once in the app initialization. I am using $http.get method to read content. So far I have tried adding file reading method in app.config and app.run. But it is not succeeded. Is this possible? If not, is there any alternative way of doing it? Following is my file read function.

```
 function getColumnName(){
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get('scripts/columnNames.json').then(function(response){
                YOUR_VARIABLE = response.data;
                deferred.resolve(response.data);
            },function(error){
                deferred.reject(error);
            }
        );
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

Comment: Is this more like a settings file or are these fixed values? If these are more like fixed values I would advice to use [Angular Constants](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#constant). Another possible solution you can implement would be adding the json context as variable to your angular application. You can place this variable in a seperate file and load it on your index.html.

Comment: @StefanKert , yes they are fixed values. Better to use constant and agree with you.

Comment: Ok. Glad that I could help. Had this case a few months ago and searched for a way go getting things done.

Comment: For anyone who wants to do the same as above, use the **edited** code with deferred, as it will guarantee results in a stateless(http) call.

Comment: Hi @Luke. Welcome to StackOverflow. I see that you've answered your own question. However, **instead of editing your question and putting your answer in question itself, post your answer as a separate post.** See also : [Can I answer my own questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)